# Convert a epub to a pdf filew with bookmarks preserved?

Tags: pdf, calibre, epub

How can we convert a epub file to a pdf file, preserving bookmarks for toc?

I use `ebook-convert (calibre 0.8.38)` to convert [a epub file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/epub2pdf/in.epub) to [a pdf file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/epub2pdf/out.pdf).

```
$ ebook-convert in.epub out.pdf
```

The epub file has bookmarks for table of content, while the output pdf file doesn't (See the two pictures below)

I also tried

```
$ ebook-convert in.epub out.pdf --pdf-add-toc
ebook-convert: error: no such option: --pdf-add-toc
```

which failed maybe because my calibre is too old? (Anyone having the latest Calibre can help to try?)

Is there other program or online converter which may help? Thanks.

---

original epub file with bookmarks for toc:

[image]

output pdf file without bookmarks for toc (evince calls "Index" for bookmarks, and "Bookmarks" for something else):

[image]

Comment: Using calibre 2.19 converting epub to pdf went without a hitch and transferred my TOC into bookmarks/index both with GUI and CL.